# How could I refactor well better this code?

Tags: arrays, ruby, refactoring

I'm quite new in Ruby and I'm always looking for the best way to write / refactor my code. Here, I wanted to create a method which creates an array containing itself two new arrays. The first one, containing only words equal to the `size` parameter and sorted alphabetically. The second one, also sorted, with all the other words. I'm pretty sure I can improve this code but I can't find out how. Thanks for your help !

```
sentence = ["dog", "data", "ask", "my", "win", "two", "beer", "as"]

def size_splitter(array, size)
  first_array = []
  second_array = []
  final_array = []

  array.sort.each do |arr|
    if arr.size == size
      first_array << arr
    else
      second_array << arr
    end
  end
  final_array.push(first_array, second_array)
end

puts size_splitter(sentence, 3)

#result : [["ask", "dog", "two", "win"], ["as", "beer", "data", "my"]]
```

Comment: Just a note for the future, this kind of question is better for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll know for the next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually do it as a one liner using [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)

> Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.

When it says "returns two arrays", it actually means "return one array containing two arrays" which is the result you need (note, Ruby doesn't support multiple return values from a function, so the only way to return two arrays would be to wrap them in another array)

```
sentence.sort.partition { |x| x.length == 3 }
# => [["ask", "dog", "two", "win"], ["as", "beer", "data", "my"]]
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's awesome thank you max, I couldn't find that ```partition```method ! What do you mean by "Ruby doesn't support multiple return values" ? I'm not sure to understand...

Comment: Ruby always returns one object and one object *only* from a method call. This may be `nil`, but for multiple values it will be an `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better to define methods in separate files even consider using a `Module`, but for now let's just place it in the very beginning:

```rb
def size_splitter(array, size)
  ...
end

sentence = [...]
```

Next thing to point out is to use `%w[]` literals for arrays of a single word strings (containing more that one of them):

```rb
sentence = %w[dog data ask my win two beer as]
```

Next use `Array#select` (that is the method that any Array class object has) to select only the needed elements based on condition:

```rb
size = 3
array.select { |e| e.size == size }
```

This code will return and array with only elements from the original `array` (surprise!) whose size is equal to 3.

The opposite of `select` is `reject`:

```rb
size = 3
array.reject { |e| e.size == size }
```

This code will return array of element with size **not** equal to 3.

But in your case (when you need an array of both your arrays) the solution of **max pleaner** is better:

```rb
size = 3
return [
  array.select { |e| e.size == size },
  array.reject { |e| e.size == size }
]
```

is equal to:

```rb
size = 3
return array.sort.partition { |x| x.length == size }
```

But we don't need `return`-s for the last (and only) expression in a ruby method.

So my final version of your code will look like this:

```rb
def size_splitter(array, size)
  array.sort.partition { |x| x.length == size }
end

sentence = %w[dog data ask my win two beer as]

puts size_splitter(sentence, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for all those explanations installero, it helps me to figure out all this exercice, I really appreciate :)